# Distorted render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render an image, but as you can see it comes all distorted, when the actual object is not! Please, how can I solve this? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe you've given a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object (and it is enabled in render but not in preview)

Comment: Or maybe the opposite of this ^. Like you have an SS mod, but it's not enabled in the render, but visible in the preview. Usually distorted UVs come from too little geometry. But it's possible that either/or could be causing the issue.